# How to close video widget window once video is done playing QVideoWidget?

Tags: c++, qt6, qmediaplayer, qvideowidget

I want to display a video when a button is clicked and close the video widget once the video is done playing in QT 6.4, and if there is no workaround that, if I could somehow display the video in a widget I create on QTDesigner that would work well too, thank you!

```
QMediaPlayer* player = new QMediaPlayer;
player->setSource(QUrl("C:/Users/QTDev/Desktop/final.mp4"));

QAudioOutput * audioOutput = new QAudioOutput;

player->setAudioOutput(audioOutput);
audioOutput->setVolume(1.0);

QVideoWidget* videoWidget = new QVideoWidget;
player->setVideoOutput(videoWidget);

videoWidget->showFullScreen();
player->play();
```

Comment: Just connect to the [`QMediaPlayer::mediaStatusChanged`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmediaplayer.html#mediaStatusChanged) signal and act on `QMediaPlayer::EndOfMedia `.

Comment: I'm fairly new to QT, I assume connect() works somewhat like an event listener, but I haven't really used it before, could you perhaps give me a small example that I can learn from?
As in, I don't know what to pass as an argument

Comment: If you're new to Qt then please take some time to read about [signals/slots](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html) and review the ["examples" documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtexamplesandtutorials.html).